# How to properly comment/document for Map object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Map object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Eg,

```
private _fruit: Map<string, FruitDetail> = new Map();
```

It normally comes with methods like,

```
public setFruit(fruitName: string, fruitDetail: FruitDetail) {...}

public getFruit(fruitName: string): FruitDetail {...}
```

But only the `string` type is declared in property, how should I let others know it should be `fruitName` not `fruitColor`?

Comment: are they both defined as string fruitName and fruitColor?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya well, it’s just an example. I’m curious how to clearly let others know what I’m doing for this Map and how they should manage the structure if they plan to extend or partially change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to document the meaning of the map keys, you could use a type alias:

```
private _fruit: Map<FruitName, FruitDetail> = new Map();

// Outside the class
type FruitName = string;
```

The `FruitName` is only for documentation; if you also define `FruitColor = string`, TypeScript won't report an error if you mix up `FruitName`s and `FruitColor`s.  If you want an error, you can use a "branded" string type.  A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+branded+string+types) found me a few tutorials, including [this one](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html#using-interfaces), which is closest to what I have used on one of my projects.